# Get authorization token from headers into fetch reactj

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using fetch in my react project to fetch data from an API which is authenticated using a token and my login end-point in the postman return the token in authorization header, you can see
[image]

and this's my login funtion in reactjs project

```
 async login(dataLogin) {

  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/login`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: dataLogin
  });
  
  const data = await response
  
  console.log(response.headers);
   console.log(response.headers.Authorization);
   console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'));

  return data;}
```

[image]
you can see that response.headers.authorization return undefined and

> response.headers.get('Authorization') return null.

and you can see in my browsers' Network panel
[image]

please anyone know how to get the authorization token from the headers?

Comment: Returning the token in the response headers is an odd choice. You should return it in the response body.

Answer (score 2):

To access value of response header server must return header name in [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header. Without it `Authorization` is inaccessible in browser.

Comment: Have been debugging this problem for almost 2 hours, until I saw this. This should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to login using API, then you should receive data i.e. Authorization token or anything else in the response of call.

Check what is the response you're getting when you called an API, it should probably be like
`response.data`
First you need to check the same in Postman.

Answer (score -1):

```js
response.headers.get('Authorization')
```

---

**Edit:**

Since you are getting `null`, consider that:

> The Authorization header is usually, but not always, sent after the
> user agent first attempts to request a protected resource without
> credentials.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Therefore, instead of using postman, in order to see the response header, use the browsers' Network panel.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.